# Trouble With Audiofile Loading Automatically instead of during event

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to get the audiofile to load only when the textbox is clicked on. However, the event doesn't seem to apply to the element I'm trying to declare and instead plays automatically. I have been testing in the latest firefox browser.

```
<audio id="sGreeting" src="SantaGreeting.mp3"></audio>
<form action="" name="theForm">
<label for="name">What is your name?</label>
    <input name="name1" type="text"/>
</form>

<script>
  var nameEntry = document.theForm.name1;
  nameEntry.addEventListener("onfocus", document.getElementById('sGreeting').play());   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it's because of the .play() statement. This is assigning the result of the .play function to the onfocus event.

What I needed to do was refer to document.getElementById('sGreeting').play

Without parenthesis '()' at the end, that way the event simply calls the function and doesn't assign its value to the event.